# ThreadLocal on Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, thread-local

I would like to make some request-wide data available in my app engine application.

Examples:

- The URL for which the request was made.
- Authentication information.

I see that `ThreadLocal` is on GAE's [JRE whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html).

Is `ThreadLocal`a good and safe way to make this information available?  Are there alternative / better / more accepted ways?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is an accepted practice to store these things in a `ThreadLocal`. However, a more preferable approach is to pass these values around (as method arguments) wherever they are needed, instead of reaching for them. It's more preferable, because it's more testable at least.